# Fork how many processes created confused

Tags: c, linux, process, operating-system, fork

Say i have the following program

```
pid_t pid = fork();  // fork #1
pid = fork();        // fork #2
```

So now what we have:

1. Fork #1 creates an additional processes. so now we have two
   processes.
2. Fork #2 is executed by two processes, creating two
   processes, for a total of four.

My confusion is after the first fork we will have two processes P1(parent) and C1 (child). each process will execute the second fork once. so shouldn't we have 6 processes since P1 will create two more and C1 also? or is it that only the P1 can execute the second fork creating  P2 C2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good general rule is that one process calls `fork` but two return from it (assuming it works, of course).

Both returning processes continue executing *after* the return from the `fork`, something I suspect you man not have fully understood based on your confusion.

That means you go from one process to two in the first fork, then *each* of those processes calls `fork` again, so the process count doubles then doubles again (1 -> 4). Basically:

```
1  -> fork#1 -+-> 1 -> fork#2 -+-> 1
              |                |
              |                +-> 3
              |
              +-> 2 -> fork#2 -+-> 2
                               |
                               +-> 4
```

Comment: so fork() will be called based on how many processes we have before it?

Answer (score 0):

C1 won't execute the fork twice, only once.
P1 will execute it twice which will result in C1 and C2.
C1 will execute the second fork only.
the end result is 4 processes.
here is a visualization:
P1 -> C2 second fork
| first
V fork
C1 -> C3 second fork of child process