# How many process and thread does this code create?

Tags: c, multithreading, fork, pid

```
int main( ) {
  pid t pid1, pid2;
  pid1 = fork ( );
  pid2 = fork ( );
  if (pid1 == 0) { /* child process */
    pthread_create (. . .);
  }
  if (pid2 > 0) { /* parent process */
    pthread_create (. . .);
  }
}
```

I think it creates 8 processes.

```
  if (pid2 > 0) { /* parent process */
    pthread_create (. . .);
  }
```

I am not sure about the number of threads though. Does each thread have child with pid 0 and pid greater than 0, so 16 threads?

Comment: Why not just run it and find out?

Comment: It is like a question "how many processes this code creates" is asked weekly: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+processes+fork+create+site%3Astackoverflow.com. For example, [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182577/fork-how-many-processes-created-confused) is about 2-forks-code, like yours one.